# Is there anything like certbot (auto-renewal) for paid SSL certs?

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, certbot

For maximumum compatibility, I want to use simple DV PositiveSSL certs, similar to what Let's Encrypt does.

But the biggest pain in the neck is that I can't find anything which renews automatically when the time comes, like certbot/Let's Encrypt.

Are there any other CLI/script options for paid SSL certs to be auto-renewed, without me having to

- Paste in my CSR file
- Wait on an email to confirm
- Wait on an email to get my certs
- Paste in the contents of the cert files on my server
- Reboot apache

Certbot makes it so nice and simple, but only works with Let's Encrypt (which, after Sept 2016, loses a lot of compatibility with slightly older browsers/OSes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but only works with Let's Encrypt

No, that is not true. Although LE is Certbot's default service, the same ACMEv2 issuance protocol has been implemented by a few other CAs. For example, I have already used it with Sectigo OV certificates (who had a very similar cross-signing issue earlier this year) and with DigiCert OV.

(You just specify a different "--server" URL in Certbot, and when registering the ACME account for the first time provide an "--eab-hmac-key" for associating it with your actual ordering account on that service, a feature specifically added for use by commercial operators.)

The same goes for all other ACMEv2 clients, not just Certbot. The list of CAs supporting this protocol is short but non-zero, and with the recent push by browsers to reduce certificate lifetimes further and further (emphasizing automated renewals), it's only likely to grow.

---

Aside from ACME, some CAs do also offer the older SCEP protocol as well as custom ordering APIs (DigiCert has *two*). These *may* be limited to bulk/enterprise plans though, and you'll have more difficulties finding usable clients.